# In Activity detect closure of PopupWindow

Tags: android, android-activity, popupwindow

I have an Activity from which I call a PopupWindow. My question is how can this Activity get to know that the PopupWindow has been closed and it (Activity) needs to refresh itself? onResume does not seem to be working. It works for Intents, but not PopupWindow. Am I missing the obvious here? TIA.

-sph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement refreshing logic of you activity in

> [PopupWindow.OnDismissListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.OnDismissListener.html)

Comment: Got it. Don't know how I missed it. Thanks Android Coader.